# Find text in VS including .sln and .csproj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How to find text including .sln and .csproj? I wanted to search package version present in all the project. I have instance where package version is not captured in npm but is present in .csproj file and hence causes issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio has option called ["Find in Files"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dechx2tz.aspx). You open the form, type your text you want to search for and you can actually set the file types. As example, if you want to search project files, solution files and code files, you can set filter as

> *.??proj;*.sln;*.vb;*.cs;*.asax;*.ashx

We have mixture of c# and vb, so `*.??proj` covers all of them.

Click "Find All"

When your search is over, in the result window, click on the line and it will take you to the line in file where your match is found

**Important Note**

> When field *"Look in"* is set to *"Entire Solution"* or *"Current Project"* or *"All open documents"* search will totally skip `*.??proj` files even if they are listed in filter.
>   If you unload the project and open project file for edit, *"Entire Solution"* and *"All open documents"* options will search through opened project file.

**Also keep in mind**

Bugs have been reported to MS about functionality of *Find in Files*. Especially VS2017 is affected. So, based on the VS version you have, something may or may not work correctly. I know that *subfolders* feature was affected. I've seen this searching only 3 folders deep but not deeper. Here you can look at or [report new bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)

Comment: How to appy filter  `*.??proj;*.sln;*.vb;*.cs;*.asax;*.ashx `

Comment: @RajaramShelar Use field "Look at these file types" --> https://static1.squarespace.com/static/503beff0e4b0411ce5b1ed29/t/508d84e3e4b0d28844dda9b2/1351451875446/csproj.PNG  Use "Find all" button

Comment: @RajaramShelar Am I spinning my wheels here? I use this function every day. Open Visual Studio. go to Edit-Find And Replace-Find In Files. Enter or select  the directory you want to search in. Check "Include subfolders". Add your file type filters (\*.\* - will do all file types) aand click "Find All". What is not clear? What *"No luck"* means? you not running search, you not finding results? you don't know what to do? You got to define your "no luck". May be tell us what you see on the screen?

Comment: Fantastic! thanks for explanation. I used to search in solution instead of directory. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: @RajaramShelar If you want only search specific file, for example, you may have 100 projects in directory and you need to search and change (you can do "Replace in files") specific value. Good example changing `AssemblyInfo` files. For this you can in file type filter put `AssemblyInfo.??` - this will find only stuff in AssemblyInfo.cs and Assemblyinfo.vb

Comment: @T.S. it appears this only works if you have the .csproj files already open and search "All Open Documents". I tried searching "Entire Solution", both with & without "External Items", and it would not find any matches. May want to update your answer to clarify this.

Comment: @TobyJ, I couldn't make those instructions work either, but I worked it out, I've stuck it in another answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008189/1879019

Comment: @tomRedox Good that you posted screens. II was explaining exactly that. Uncheck "display names only" - you will get actual code line and exact usage. I think, people who have issues with these instruction simply don't set right filters. Make a small mistake in filter and you will get no results. But you know, this is kind funny. People here are software developers and they can't get this?

Comment: @T.S. Oh well spotted, I'd forgotten I had find in files on, I've added a note that that's not needed in my answer!

Comment: @T.S. then your instructions are incomplete. Selecting "Find In Files", at least in VS 2017, will default the "Look In" box to the last option you used, and if you have a solution already open then "Entire Solution" is the default. Maybe they have combined several different features into a single feature. Either way, your instructions don't mention anywhere that the user must select the folder to search in.

Comment: @T.S. You are implying that "Find in Files" behaves the exact same way each time and that is not true. The fact that "Entire Solution", which is the default behavior for Find In Files, does not actually search `csproj` files, is confusing and inconsistent behavior. Yet you are insisting that if someone does not automatically understand this difference it's because they aren't smart enough. You said "Find in files searches anything on hard drive", and that is absolutely incorrect for VS 2017. It only searches everything on hard drive if you change the default. Your answer is no longer correct.

Comment: @TobyJ I simply misunderstood your complaint, a behavior which I didn't realize existed. But now I see what you're referring to. VS2012 has same behavior. It seem that VS completely skips `*.??proj` files when *"Look In"* is set to *"Entire Solution"* or *"Current Project"*. Added a note to answer. Thanks

Comment: @RajaramShelar May be you fell victim of the problem we just solved - read latest comments and update note.

Answer (score 19):

In VS:

Go to Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files, which opens this screen:

[image]

Then press the ellipsis button to the right of Look In that's circled in red above.

That opens a screen where you can select folders:

[image]

use the right arrow between the lists (circled in red) to select which folder(s) to search, choose the ones that contain the .proj or .sln files you want searched.

Press OK

Back on the Find and Replace screen you can add the filter (similar to that mentioned in the other answer) if you want just project files, e.g. *.??proj;*.sln;*.asax;*.ashx

[image]

And then finally the Find buttons will be enabled, hit Find All and that will return results that include project files:

[image]

NB: @T.S. just made the very good point that I have 'Display file names only' ticked in the screenshots. You don't need that to make this work, I had that ticked because I have minified files in my project and they cause the Find Results window to slow to a crawl if they are included in the search results!

Comment: Thinks worked for me. You can also give the Folder set(s) a name. Neat.

Comment: When using tens of projects in solution, but in different directories (outside of main solution directory), this method is very, very tedious.

Comment: @SylwesterZarębski I haven't tried this, but in the second screenshot it looks like you can define a folder set, which sounds like it might allow you to create a reusable list of folders to search.  Also, I think the search is probably recursive, so if there's a single directory somewhere further up the tree that all your directories sit in, you might be able to just choose that higher level directory to search.  Like I say, I haven't tried either of those, but you could give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

For me, switching `Solutions and Folders` view and doing the global search `.csproj` file types did the trick!

[image]

Searching among `.csproj` files only works when you're on Folder View.

Comment: It is not applicable if using solution with projects outside of solution directory. Folder view shows only solution directory and not all projects directories.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio:

- open "Find in Files"
- Under 'Find what:' enter the text you want to search
- Under 'Look in:' click on ... 3 dots, it will open 'Choose Search Folders'
- Select the respective folder of your solution from 'Available folders'
- Once folder is identified, move it to right using > under 'Selected Folders:' and press 'OK'.
- Now click on 'Find All' in Search popup.

It will search the text in all files including .sln and .csproj files.

Answer (score -1):

You can do search in project items in visual studio. The only way to search in csproj and sln files you should do use for example windows explorer.  [this](http://www.anujvarma.com/searching-through-and-editing-csproj-files/) may be helpful

Comment: Thanks. Can we have anything in VS itself?

Comment: *"The only way to search in csproj and sln files you should do use for example windows explorer"* - **wrong!**